# Find the normal force on beam in asymmetrical scenario

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, momentum, torque

> A thin beam with evenly distributed mass $M$ and length $L$ is resting on two spikes as shown below.
>
> [image]
>
> What is the vertical normal force $F_l$ on the beam exerted by the left spike?

**Solution**

The solution uses something called the "moment-torque theorem". They use the theorem on the spike to the left and comes up with the equation
$$F_l \cdot \frac{2}{3}L-Mg \bigg(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)L =0$$
From where they conclude that $F_l=\frac{1}{4}M$

It is not intuitively clear to me at all how they arrive at that equation. Can anybody explain that? Furthermore, is it possible to solve this problem by force analysis? If so, I would be very interested to see that.

Comment: Have you taken a basic statics course?

Comment: @BobD No, never. This is a problem from a basic physics course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Furthermore, is it possible to solve this problem by force analysis?
> If so, I would be very interested to see that.

Yes, it is possible. Use **Newton's Second Law**: in order for the beam to be immobile all **forces and torques** acting on it must cancel out.

Start with a force body diagram (FBD):

[image: Beam and forces]

All forces must cancel out, so:

$$F_l+F_r-Mg=0\tag{1}$$

All torques must cancel out. Here we've taken the torques *about the point* $x=0$ ($x=L/2$ is the CoG of the beam):

$$Mg\frac{L}{2}-F_r \frac{2L}{3}=0\tag{2}$$

Then solve for $F_l$ and $F_r$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$F_r=\frac{3}{4}Mg$$

$$F_l+\frac{3}{4}Mg=Mg\Rightarrow \boxed{F_l=\frac{1}{4}Mg}$$

(Note that you wrote $F_l=\frac{1}{4}M$ which is incorrect, as it is a mass and not a force)

Answer (score 2):

Newton laws are actually valid for a point particle.

However, the bad news is that we never have point particles in real life. All of them are extended bodies. For example, the typical rectangle that represents a car moving.

We've been always placing the weight on it center (it is correct), the friction next to the floor, and so on.

Well, all this is correct if the body has only translation. Obviously, the car can move back and forth, but it cannot rotate (and, if it can, that's truly a problem haha).

But what happens when we consider rotation? It all changes. When a body can rotate, Newton's laws are not usually enough.

That's why we define a new magnitude, called "moment of forces" or "torque". If is defined as

$\vec{\tau}=\vec{r}\times\vec{F}$, where $\vec{r}$ is the radius from a point to where the force is applied.

Think of a steering wheel: what will happen if you do these two forces?

[image]

According to Newton's laws, we have two equal forces in opposite directions, so the object should not move...

However, we KNOW that that's not what actually happens.
The object first **rotates** until the two forces are aligned. Then, when they are aligned, they finally cancel each other.

So, in short, what you have to do is solving translation and rotation separately:

1. Translation works as always, just apply Newton's laws, just as if all forces were applied on the same point. I mean, just do $\sum F_x = m a_x$ and $\sum F_y=m a_y$

When you first solve translation, you do not care about where the forces are applied. You only add up vertical components and horizontal components.

2. Rotation. When you have finally solved translation, then you should care about rotation.

If we want the beam NOT to rotate, then we must impose the torque to be 0.

0 torque ↔ no change in rotation.

The torque, roughly speaking, measures the ability of a force to cause rotation. Read abbout it, it's quite long to explain.

So you should then solve for $\sum \tau =0 $

Check that torque CARES about where the forces are applied, via the distance $r$. Like the steering wheel, the same forces can cause rotation or not, depending on where they are applied.

It is convenient to choose the origin of torques on the rotation axis / rotation point.

So we can use Newton's laws when we don't have point particles, but whenever rotation plays a role, we need more tools.

Comment: Thanks for not supplying worked solutions and instead just giving the concepts :)

Comment: @BioPhysicist You are right, of course. I have revised mine.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption underlying the question is the beam is in equilibrium, that is, the sum of all the forces acting on the beam is zero and the sum of all the torques  acting on the beam is zero so that the beam neither translates or rotates, or

$\sum F_{i}=0$ and $\sum \tau_{i}=0$

(BTW in statics we generally use the term "moment" instead of "torque" and would write $\sum M_{i}=0$ instead $\sum \tau_{i}=0$. But here that might be confused with mass $M$)

The "spikes" referred to in the problem are what are called "pin supports" in statics. They can resist horizontal and vertical (normal) forces but not torques (twisting forces). Think of them like hinges.

To find the normal or vertical force $F_1$ you draw what is called a free body diagram (FBD) of the beam. That's a diagram that shows all the external forces acting on the beam. Those forces are the weight of the beam (Mg) acting vertically downward at the center of the beam, and the reaction forces at each spike. See the diagram below.

The reactions at the spikes can be theoretically horizontal and/or vertical, but since the only force acting on the beam is its weight, the reactions are only vertical. So your FBD will show an upward reaction $F_1$ on the left spike an upward reaction force $F_2$ on the right spike.

Each of these vertical forces causes a torque at any point along the beam of $\tau =Fd$ where $d$ is the distance between the  point of application of the force and the point on the beam.  In statics we call this distance the "moment arm". We can multiply the force times the distance in this problem because torque is due to a force acting perpendicular to the moment arm and all the forces act perpendicular to the beam.  If a force acted at an angle, you would only use the the component of the force that acts perpendicular to the acting perpendicular to the moment arm.

Since the reaction forces are located on the spikes, at the spikes $d$ (the moment arm) is zero and so the reaction forces at a spike cause no torque at that spike. Consequently, if we take the sum of the torques about spike 2, the only forces that cause a torque about spike 2 is the weight of the beam and the normal reaction force $F_1$.

Given this, and the FBD below, you should be able to solve for $F_{1}$

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the other answers, the way to do this is requiring the net torque to be zero.

There are three forces: the two spikes and gravity which can be regarded as acting on the middle. The sensible thing to do is to consider the torques about the point through which one of these forces acts, so that one of the three torques is zero (because no lever arm) and you can just balance the other two.

You’ll get the same answer regardless, but it may strike you as a bit more intuitive to choose the middle of the beam as the pivot point rather than one of the spikes. The distance from this pivot to the left spike is $L/2$ and the distance to the right spike is $L/6$ in the other direction. So for the torques to balance the force at the right spike has to be three times that at the left.

Since the total force from both spikes has to add up to the weight of the beam, you can see that a quarter of the weight goes on the left spike and three quarters in the right.

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer Gert provided it all starts (always) from a free body diagram. What was missing from Gert's answer is *where* the weight of the beam is acting through (at least from the picture).

[image: fbd]

From the above, make sure the sum of forces equal 0 **and** the sum of torques about an arbitrary point is zero also. Those two equations are solved for the two forces.